# WordPress loads whole jQuery UI library

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My wordpress loads whole jQuery UI library

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.position.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.menu.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.button.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
```

Is this normal? I didn't noticed the same behavior earlier.

Comment: I think it is not normal and I think that that files are loaded by a plugin. Have you tried to deactivate all the installed plugins to check if this behavior stops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery-UI is *included* in every default WP installation.
Whether it is *loaded* depends on your theme and/or plugin(s).

Three Options:

- live with it
- disable plugins one by one (and switch theme), figure out which is responsible and whether that's needed
- manually [deregister](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) it (something, i.e. a plugin, will probably break)

Comment: Thanks, it was http://wp-events-plugin.com/, will write to them about it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "Events-Manager" plugin?
There is an option to disable loading of unnecessary scripts.
I found this to be the cause of all the extraordinary jquery.ui files.

You can change the loading here:
visit the backend of your wordpress install > Events > Settings > General Tab > Performance Optimization
THEN
Limit JS file loading?
Change this to YES

Limit loading of our CSS files?
Change this to YES also.

Hit [ Save Changes (All) ]
And you should be set

Comment: if this helps, please upvote my answer

Comment: Why do you think the OP is using this particular plugin?

Comment: Because I leaved a comment in answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, My website used to load over 20 jquery ui scripts. I fixed it by disabling the plugin : Powie's Page Cloud Widget

If anyone has this issue, just disable all plugins and enable one by one. Because only plugins are responsible for this problem.