# Homepage loads many unnecessary jquery-ui files

Tags: jquery

In order to speed up loadtime I try to avoid unnecessary loads. In the Google report (and in my html) I see that many unwanted files are loaded, as jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1, core-min, mouse-min, button-min, widget-min and more.
I am certain I do not need or use them but they cause (among more) a terrible loadtime.
I am using theme Twenty Seventeen.

What should I do to avoid loading these jquery-min files?

The site: [www.vakantiehuisverhuur.eu](https://www.vakantiehuisverhuur.eu/).

Regards
Rudolph Smits, NL

Comment: You can try to find a responsible plugin by disabling them one by one like mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114312/wordpress-loads-whole-jquery-ui-library).

Answer (score 0):

I can not explain this but this seems to be **solved**.

Using Autoptimize already but now **aggregating** javascript in stead of **minify** did the job. I could not do this before because it made Contact Form 7 fail to redirect to a "thank you" page after sending a form. With the help of the author that has been solved so that I can "aggregate" now.

I saw people from all over the world visiting my site. Thank you for your intention to help. Moped, especially to you!

Regards
Rudolph Smits, Netherlands

Answer (score 0):

add the following codes to the functions.php file:

```
// Remove Query Strings

function _remove_script_version( $src ){

    $parts = explode( '?ver', $src );
    return $parts[0];
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );

// Remove jquery migrate
function dequeue_jquery_migrate( $scripts ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && ! empty( $scripts->registered['jquery'] ) ) {
    $scripts->registered['jquery']->deps = array_diff(
        $scripts->registered['jquery']->deps,
        [ 'jquery-migrate' ]
    );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'dequeue_jquery_migrate' );
```

Comment: You should explain your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find out what "migrate" does I found this wordpress plugin:
https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/remove-jquery-migrate/

I think it does the same as the code of Maynor Peralta above but his code will do it more efficiently. I will try do apply that next week.

Yesterday I got a ban from Google Recaptcha v3 due to - I think - to many same test actions. I will have to wait till this is over. ;-(

Regards
Rudolph Smits